# How to pick the most expensive shipping rate

Tags: rules, commerce

I have a Drupal 7 site with Drupal Commerce e-shop. For most of the products I charge a flat rate, in 3 tiers, some products cost € 5 to ship, some € 6 and some € 25, implemented as three flat rate shipping services.

I have set up rules to apply the correct shipping rate. These rules check for the presence of applicable products and - if found:

1. Delete all shipping line items from an order
2. Apply shipping rate to an order

I've set the weight of the rules so they are evaluated cheap-to-expensive. I figured the expensive shipping would then replace the cheap shipping.

I get both though. My check-out form shows:

-- Article listing --
Subtotal    € 20
Shipping    € 6
Shipping    € 25
Order total € 51

Instead I just want to charge € 25 for shipping.
Is the current behavior the expected behavior? Is my current approach wrong and misguided?

Answer (score 0):

seems like your 6€ shipping rate does not have a maximum, so it gets listed again ?